# How to import 'cluster' and 'pylab' into Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, data-science

I would like to use Pycharm to write some data science code and I am using Visual Studio Code and run it from terminal. But I would like to know if I could do it on Pycharm? I could not find some modules such as cluster and pylab on Pycharm? Anyone knows how I could import these modules into Pycharm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

executing

```
 pip install cluster
```

for cluster and

```
pip install matplotlib
```

for pylab in the pycharm terminal which is located at the bottom of the screen is another method for installing those two packages. (if you want to import pylab, use **from matplotlib import pylab**).

[image]

Additionally you can install any package in PyPI into pycharm virtual environment using this.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Preferences Tab -> Project Interpreter, there's a + symbol that allows you to view and download packages. From there you should be able to find cluster and pylab and install them to PyCharm's interpreter. After that you can import them and run them in your scripts.

Alternatively, you may switch the project's interpreter to an interpreter that has the packages installed already. This can be done from that same menu.

Comment: I could find cluter and pylab in PyCharm interpreter. Not sure why. It shows 'nothing to show'. @YungGun

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in [Scientific Mode](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html) feature in Pycharm. You can activate it by selecting `View > Scientific Mode`.